# Add class to preparrent element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tell me please how to add a class to the previous element. For example:

```js
function menu_js() {
  if (menu_ul.length > 0) {
    menu_ul.hide();
    menu_a.click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
        menu_a.removeClass('active');
        menu_ul.filter(':visible').slideUp('normal');
        $(this).addClass('active').next().stop(true, true).slideDown('normal');
      } else {
        $(this).removeClass('active');
        $(this).next().stop(true, true).slideUp('normal');
      }
    });

    if (menu_current.length > 0) {
      if (menu_current.parent().attr('id') != "menu_mob") {
        menu_current.parent().show();
        menu_current.parent().parent().addClass('activeLi');
      } else {
        menu_current.addClass('activeLi');
      }
    }
  }
}

var menu_ul = $('#main .liste-produits'),
  menu_a = $('#main .categories-item'),
  menu_current = $('#main .current'),
  menu_ul_first = $('#main .liste-categories li:first-child .liste-produits'),
  menu_parent_open = $('#main .liste-categories li:first-child .categories-item');

menu_js();

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = window.location;
  var element = $('ul.liste-produits a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
  });
  $(element).parentsUntil('ul.sidebar-menu', 'li').addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav id="main" class="menu_boutique-area">
  <ul class="liste-categories">


    <li><strong class="categories-item"><a><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Catalog 1 </a></strong>
      <ul class="liste-produits">
        <li><a href="/catalog1/subcat1.html" class="produit-item"><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Subcat 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/catalog1/subcat2.html" class="produit-item"><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Subcat 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/catalog1/subcat3.html" class="produit-item"><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Subcat 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li><strong class="categories-item"><a><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Catalog 2 </a></strong>
      <ul class="liste-produits">
        <li><a href="/catalog2/subcat1.html" class="produit-item"><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Subcat 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/catalog2/subcat2.html" class="produit-item"><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Subcat 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/catalog2/subcat3.html" class="produit-item"><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Subcat 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>


    <li><strong class="categories-item"><a><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Catalog 3 </a></strong>
      <ul class="liste-produits">
        <li><a href="/catalog3/subcat1.html" class="produit-item"><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Subcat 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="/catalog3/subcat2.html" class="produit-item"><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Subcat 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="/catalog3/subcat3.html" class="produit-item"><em class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right">&nbsp;&nbsp;</em> Subcat 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>


  </ul>
</nav>
```

Using `var url = window.location;` I define on which page the user is located to add to the item in the menu the class `active` at the moment it adds a class to the `ul.liste-categories li` element. I need to add the same class for the item above.

In fact, it should work like this: the menu determines which page is this and deploys the item where the sub-item is located on which the page is located.

I'm bad at Javascript, but as far as I understand it's only necessary to add the `active` class to the main item.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. But use `.prev()` to get the previous sibling, and `.parent()` to get the element above it in the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: Adding to Barmar's comment, instead of `.parent().parent()`, use `.closest(selector)` or `.parents(selector)`

Comment: It did not work, I need to have the page where the page is located when loading the page. For example, if I go to the "/catalog3/subcat1.html" page, Catalog 3 should unfold.